# how to pass value from input form into another page in laravel

Tags: php, html, web, laravel-5, netbeans

Excuse me, i'm new in learning about Laravel and I have a problem about show data value from form input.
I have create.blade.php :

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <h1><b>Create an account</b></h1>
        <h5>Welcome to Konoha Village</h5>
    </div>
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    @if(isset($name))
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        Halo <strong>{{$name}}</strong>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">$times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    @endif

    <div class="form">
        <form action="{{ url('final-test') }}" method="post" id="form1">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Full Name"/>                
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input style="cursor:pointer" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" value="Show into Dashboard">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

and my controller with name AccController.php :

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AccController extends Controller
{
    public function create() {
        return view('home.create');
    }

    public function show(Request $r) {
        $soul = $r ->name;

        $pesan = "Your name is {$r->name}";
    }
}
```

and my route in web.php :

```
//route to get play form
Route::get ('start',        'AccController@create' )->name('home.create');
Route::post('final-test',  'AccController@show');
```

i want to show in another page view that i called show.blade.php :

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

<div>
    {{$name = Input::get('name')}}
    <h1>Your name is {{ $pesan }}</h1> </div>   

@endsection
```

nothing's error in the end but it couldn't show the value from the input form, would you help me please?
Regards, Aga.

Comment: You need to return a view in your `show()` method like you did in your `create()` method

Comment: i did, but still nothing's happend in it, just add return view right?

Comment: You did? Your `public function show(Request $r) {` says you don't.

Comment: i did, but  it still said that "The page has expired due to inactivity.

Please refresh and try again. "

Comment: Remove `{{$name = Input::get('name')}}` from your `show.blade.php` and maybe update your question to reflect the latest code you tried

Comment: sure, i'll do it.. give me a second please

Comment: i have to wait until 90 minutes for added new questions, take a long time guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `web.php`:

```
//route to get play form
Route::get('/start', 'AccController@create')->name('home.create');
Route::post('/final-test', 'AccController@show')->name('home.show');
```

Added a name `home.show` to the route final-test.

Your `AccController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AccController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('home.create');
    }

    public function show(Request $r)
    {
        $soul = $r->name;
        return view('home.show')->with('soul', $soul);
    }
}
```

Your `show.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
<div>
    <h1>Your name is {{ $soul }}</h1>
</div>
@endsection
```

Your `create.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <h1><b>Create an account</b></h1>
        <h5>Welcome to Konoha Village</h5>
    </div>

    @if(isset($name))
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        Halo <strong>{{$name}}</strong>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">$times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    @endif

    <div class="form">
        <form action="{{ route('home.show') }}" method="post" id="form1">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Full Name"/>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input style="cursor:pointer" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" value="Show into Dashboard">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Here's where the most important change has been made: I moved `{{ csrf_field() }}` inside the form, so you don't get `The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again.` Also changed the form action to the named route `{{ route('home.show') }}`.

I kept your `<span aria-hidden="true">$times;</span>` but this will only show `$times;`, might need to tweak that.

Comment: MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: how about that?

Comment: Works totall fine here, maybe you need to `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: OMG, @kerbholz we did it.. Gosh.. i mean, so excited.. thank you buddy, you save my home work .. bless you.

Comment: Yes, **we** did it. Accept the answer and go play soccer ;)

Comment: God, i'm a woman.. i'd loved soccer for just watching it.. see ya for the next question

Answer (score 0):

You are not following conventions here. show method is to data from database. In order to show form data you have do it in store method

**HTML Code**

There should be some minor changes in html form

```
{{--Changing in just action--}}
{{-- If it doesn't accept that action then replace it with {{AccController.php@store}} --}}
<form action="AccController.php@store" method="post" id="form1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Full Name"/>                
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input style="cursor:pointer" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" value="Show into Dashboard">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        </div>

    </form>
```

Then in Controller you will get that form data in store function

```
 public function store(Request $r) {
    $soul = $r ->name;

    $pesan = "Your name is {$r->name}";
    return $pesan;

}
```

#### How to get it in route?

Well you are doing some mistakes in route.php. You just have to follow conventions which laravel provides us.

Replace your route code with this.

```
    Route::resource('/posts', 'AccController.php');
```

Here it will automatically call all by default functions of Controller and assign them particular routes. For example Below the picture

[image]

You just have to type `php artisan route:list` in terminal or command prompt and you will see list of routes which you have created and which laravel creates for you along with method, URI and name. You just have to follow conventions and it will give you results automatically
Give it a try and tell me

Comment: give me a second please

Comment: my directory in view are home folder (there are 2 file, create.blade.php and show.blade.php), layout folder and template folder

Comment: Then according to you there is no problem in answer

Comment: forgive me, i'm confused abot the detail in controller. would help to show me another example one input and how to show it in another page ?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know the whole scenario here. But Try Route::get('/final-test',  'AccController@show');

Comment: there was an error message
"    protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others)
    {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
    }"

now what can i had to edit again?

Comment: You are not following conventions

Comment: I am updating answer. Follow me

Comment: @WaodeMakaniDaga Try store function which I have written. and use routes according to laravel

Comment: If there is any problem ask me

Comment: Thank you too you man.. we'll do our best right.. keep learning.. bless you

Comment: Sure, i'd tried this too but another way has just excited to do.. but, thanks Sir, may Allahu ta'ala bless you